# How make auto click on link when load page? NOT REDERICT

Tags: jquery

Good day.

On my site i have a link:

```
<a class="fancybox iframe" href="./online_order/form.php" id="online_form_a">

This link opens another page in an Iframe

</a>
```

when click link on page load iframe.

Tell me please how make auto click when page load for iframe load auto when load page ?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  Just send a redirect.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: i smell a bad attempt to script kiddie hacking here.

Comment: @slaks see please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717008/easy-fancybox-not-open-iframe-on-wordpress-3-3

Comment: i update question, see again please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use:

```
<script>
    window.location.replace("link.php");
</script>
```

I really wouldn't recommend doing it this way as `html` already has a method to redirect users:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=YOUR-LINK-HERE" />
```

**UPDATE**: Use this to trigger the click on page load:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // add the fancy box click handler here
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#ExPRoG_online_form_a").trigger('click');
    },10);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's some AJAX action, you should fire it in some other way, if it is redirect link, you should use `window.location.replace()`.